# Login with email on codeigniter from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

i'm building an Api, i need to login in a codeigniter-restserver project with an email + password stored on my mysql database.

*this what i tried so far:*

in my **REST_Controller** i changed the `_check_login` function with this:

```
$this->load->model('Model_logiin');
$valid_logins = $this->Model_logiin->get_by(array('student_id'=>$username));
```

please take a look at the complete code here : https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver
my

Model **Model_logiin** is this:

```
class Model_logiin extends MY_Model{

protected $_table = 'students';
protected $primary_key = 'email_adress';
protected $return_type = 'array';

protected $after_get = array('remove_sensetive_data');   //specified in MY_Model class

protected function remove_sensetive_data($student){

    unset($student['ip_adress']);
    unset($student['student_id']);
    ...

    return $student;
}
}
```

The Problem: **in the login stage.. if i type anything i can login**

** if you need more info please let me know

** if the best approach for an api to not login with email just API-Key also please let me know

** i'm new to codeigniter.

Comment: Why don't you use this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814 ?

Comment: hi @faisal-ashfaq i need the login data from my database not an array of strings `$config['rest_valid_logins'] = array('admin' => '1234');`

Comment: Well, you have the data in array. What's the problem?

Comment: in the login stage.. if i type anything i can login.

Comment: The code you post here says nothing about your login logic. I assume your get_by returns a username-password pair. But show the actual the validation process?

Comment: @JoeS please take a look at the complete code here : https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: That's the master branch? Where is your own code? I don't see a _check_login function in the controllers, nor any models in the app folder.